# Geometry of the function $f(z)=z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^2$ be a complex function with $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=u+iv$. In Functions of One Complex Variable, by Conway, the author states that $f$ maps the hyperbola$x^2-y^2=c$ to the line $u=c$. Why is this true? Doesn't $f$ map $x^2-y^2=c$ to $u=(x^2-y^2)^2=c^2$? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the hyperbola implies that $y=\pm\sqrt{x^2-c}$. In the complex plane, take only those $z$ values that can be written as $z=x\pm i\sqrt{x^2-c}$. Then $$f(z)=z^2=(x\pm i\sqrt{x^2-c})^2=x^2\pm2ix\sqrt{x^2-c}+i^2(x^2-c)=c\pm2ix\sqrt{x^2-c}$$
You notice now that the real part is always $u=c$. It's easy to see that the imaginary part $v$ can take any value between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, depending on $x$.

To reply to the last question, what you were missing is that both the hyperbola and the complex number $z$ are a **pair** of real numbers $x$ and $y$